# facet_wrap not showing the second facet with geom_density_ridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to subset parts of a data you can download the csv from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n9g_jvDVRFPTm_8j-l0Ap_WT5c8Ow5s_/view?usp=share_link) and read it as `datplot`. This is what its `head` looks like:

```
> head(datplot)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  bta   electrode  value
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 b0    Fz         3.03 
2 b0    Cz         1.78 
3 b0    Pz        -1.05 
4 b0    Fz         3.78 
5 b0    Cz         2.82 
6 b0    Pz        -0.242
```

As you can see, the data has a variable named `bta` with levels `"b0"` and `"b1"` and values from a particular distribution. What I am trying to do, is wrap the two facets but I can't manage to do it.

This is the ggplot code I am using at the moment:

```
time <- "225"
col <- c("#004d8d", "#cc2701", "#e5b400")

p1 <- datplot %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x=value, y=factor(electrode, level = c('Fz','Cz','Pz')), group = electrode, color = electrode)) +
    scale_y_discrete() +
    geom_rect(data=data.frame(), inherit.aes = FALSE, mapping = aes(
      ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)), fill = "black", alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_density_ridges(data= subset(datplot, bta='b0'), scale = -0.5, alpha=0.2, show.legend = FALSE,
                        quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), 
                        vline_color = alpha("white", 0.3), aes(fill = electrode)) +
    #plotb1
    geom_density_ridges(data= subset(datplot, bta='b1'),scale = -0.5, alpha=0.5, show.legend = FALSE,
                         quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), 
                         vline_color = alpha("white", 0.6), aes(fill = electrode)) +
    facet_wrap(~bta) +
    scale_color_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +   
    scale_fill_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +
    labs(title=sprintf('%s ms.',time)) +
    ylab("Electrode") +
    xlab(TeX(r'(Signal (µV) Posteriors   $\beta_1\cdot x\; (x=1)$)')) +
    theme_light() +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
    coord_flip(xlim = c(-8, 8), ylim = c(0.4,3.05), expand = FALSE, clip = "on")
  p1
```

This code results only with the plot corresponding to `"b0"` but the other facet seems to be missing, as you can see in the following image:

[image: incomplete facet plot]

And for some reason, the data that corresponds to `"b1"` does not appear. I am probably failing in something with the code that I am unsuccesful identifying. In case it helps, the missing plot, which I plotted alone, would look something like this:

[image: b1 plot alone]

So clearly something is failing when using both `geom_density_ridges` together in the previous code.

[UPDATE]

Following a comment by @Paul, I tried to not subset the data with the following code:

```
p1 <- datplot %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x=value, y=factor(electrode, level = c('Fz','Cz','Pz')), group = electrode, color = electrode)) +
    scale_y_discrete() +
    geom_rect(data=data.frame(), inherit.aes = FALSE, mapping = aes(
      ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, xmin = -0.1 * min(stdev), xmax = 0.1 * max(stdev)), fill = "black", alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_density_ridges(data= datplot, scale = -0.5, alpha=0.5, show.legend = FALSE,
                        quantile_lines = TRUE, quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), 
                        vline_color = alpha("white", 0.3), aes(fill = electrode)) +
    facet_wrap(~bta) +
    scale_color_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +   
    scale_fill_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +
    labs(title=sprintf('%s ms.',time)) +
    ylab("Electrode") +
    xlab(TeX(r'(Signal (µV) Posteriors   $\beta_1\cdot x\; (x=1)$)')) +
    theme_light() +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
    coord_flip(xlim = c(-8, 8), ylim = c(0.4,3.05), expand = FALSE, clip = "on")
  p1
```

With the same output:

[image: without subset]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You appear to be subsetting your plots then trying to facet wrap them.  Just do `geom_density_ridges()` once without the subset then call `facet_wrap(~bta)`

Comment: Even if it made sense, still not getting the two plots. I will update the question so you can see the results.

Comment: Typo in `y=factor(electrode, level =` - should be `levels` - looking into it more but thought I'd drop this here as I noted it.

Comment: It does not seem to affect the plot though, I tried and it has the same outcome. The factor levels seem to be identified with both ```level``` and also ```levels```. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempted a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(magrittr)

# data for testing
datplot <- data.frame(
  bta = rep(c("b0", "b1"), each = 75),
  electrode = rep(c("Fz","Cz","Pz"), times = 50),
  value = runif(150,-2,5)
)

time <- "225"
col <- c("#004d8d", "#cc2701", "#e5b400")

p1 <- datplot %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=value, y=factor(electrode, levels = c('Fz','Cz','Pz')), group = electrode, color = electrode)) +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = -0.5, alpha=0.2,
                      quantile_lines = TRUE, 
                      quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), 
                      vline_color = alpha("white", 0.3), 
                      aes(fill = electrode)) +
  facet_wrap(~bta) +
  coord_flip(xlim = c(-8, 8), ylim = c(0.4,3.05), expand = FALSE, clip = "on")
p1
```

This produces a faceted plot which I think meets the meat of the request - there is much to be done to match desired aesthetics but this should provide a start point from which you can tweak the appearance.

Comment: With your code I identified what was the problem, it is in the ```geom_rect```. This cannot be transferred into the two different facets. Unfortunately, this is another different question, but you definitely helped identify the problem. Thanks very much @Paul!! I will make a new question for the ```geom_rect``` because it is a reference bar that is needed in my visualization.

Comment: Also, I didn't need to ask again, the response to my follow-up question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740231/ggplot-annotate-each-facet-with-different-geom-rect-dimensions) in case someone is interested. Cheers!